# Why my website not opening all of a sudden?

Tags: html, url, cpanel, web-hosting

Few days back, I was working on a website and successfully uploaded it as well. When I checked it, it was working fine on all devices but now from two days, my website is not working all of a sudden.

I have all my files at right placed in cpanel and didn't even touch them for several days. I have checked and surveyed my website for broken links also but didn't got any success in reestablishing my website back to normal. It's been two days now, since my site is down. I am new to all this and that's why I can't figure it out!

Comment: "Not working" and "not opening" is not really a clear description of what happens when you try to access your page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies with DNS. So the answer for this question is, to resolve DNS issues

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried contacting your web hosting service provider? They are the best people to answer your question if you say all the files are correct.

Comment: Yes files are correct... And it seems like, as if that is the last option left for me now... I will surely contact them but just wanted to know if I can do something at my end before contacting them... Thanks for your views